# Prove by induction that $n^2>7n+1$ for all $n \ge 8$

Tags: induction

So in my math book I came across this proof by induction.

It states:

**Example** Prove that $n^2>7n+1$ $\forall n\ge8$

**Solution** The result is true when n=8 because $8^2=64$ and $7*8+1=57$.

Suppose it is true when $n$ is any number $k\ge8$ that is $k^2>7k+1$ Then.

$(k+1)^2 = k^2 +2k +1 > (7k+1)+2k+1=7(k+1)+1+(2k-6)$

Since $k\ge8$, $2k-6$ is a natural number and the last expression above is greater than $7(k+1)+1$. The induction step is verified, and so the result is true $\forall n\ge8$.

**My question** Can you just add natural numbers to the equation? Like in this case $(2k-6)$ just to make the statement true? Since

$7(k+1)+1+(2k-6)>7(k+1)+1$

I understand that we want use our induction hypothesis $k^2>7k+1$ in our induction step like this $k^2+2k+1>7k+1+2k+1$ and then prove that $7k+1+2k+1>7(k+1)+1$

Which is what the $(2k-6)$ gives us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we did not add natural numbers to the equation. We can of course drop a positive quantity in  $a=b+y > b$ if $y > 0$.

\begin{align}
(7k+1)+2k+1 &=(7k+7-6)+2k+1 \\
&=(7k+7)-6+2k+1 \\
&=7(k+1) + (2k-6)+1 \\
&>7(k+1)+1, \text{since 2k-6 > 0}
\end{align}

Comment: Don't you mean (7k+7-6)+2k+1 insteand of (7k+7-6)+2k-1?

Comment: yes, you are right...thanks. been drinking too much ... oh dear...

Answer (score 1):

I think it is cleaner to argue without induction. If $n$ is a positive integer and $n\ge 8$, then $7n$ is both less than $n^2$ and a multiple of $n$, so at most $n^2-n$ and therefore $7n+1$ is at most $n^2-n+1<n^2$.

Answer (score 0):

without induction you can write
$$n^2-2\cdot \frac{7}{2}+\frac{49}{4}-\frac{53}{4}>0$$ and this is $$\left(n-\frac{7}{2}\right)^2>\frac{53}{4}$$ so we have  $$n>\frac{7}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{53}}{2}$$

Comment: How did you get the second line?

Answer (score 0):

$n\geq 8\Rightarrow n^2\geq 8n = 7n +n \geq7n +8 >7n +1$

(why induction?)

Do I miss anything?

Comment: Well my question is not how to prove that $n^2>7n+1$. It's about what's done in the induction step.